# How to change name of attribute

Tags: jquery, html

how I can change the name of attribute, for example, I have "rel", and I would like to change it to "rel2" when site is ready, is it possible somehow?

Comment: You can use the `attr` method to create an attribute with any name, however you should note that `rel2` is an invalid attribute, and may mean your page gets rendered incorrectly. If you need to store corollary data with an element, use `data`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — Invalid markup does not trigger quirks mode. That is determined by Doctype sniffing (and sometimes by IE specific meta tags).

Comment: Why do you want to replace it?

Answer (score 2):

```
var oldrel = $(el).attr('rel');
$(el).attr('rel2',oldrel).removeAttr('rel');
```

Comment: I have changed your code. No need to select/get element two tomes.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new attribute with the value of old attribute. Then remove the old attribute.

```
$("[rel]").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("rel2",$(this).attr("rel"));
    $(this).removeAttr("rel");
});
```

Comment: A selector inside a selector? That's overuse!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon can you explain more? then i can improve my answer

Comment: You have an extra `$(...)` wrapper on the first line of the function.

Comment: this is enough : `$(this).attr("rel2",$(this).attr("rel")).removeAttr("rel");`. And while you are the, you could cache `$(this)`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon ohh sorry for that.. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

No, strictly speaking it's not possible to change the name of an attribute.

If you want an attribute with a different name and the same value, you have to remove the current attribute and add a new attribute with the new name and the same value as the previous attribute.